# QHBoxLayout doesn't use all of the space

Tags: pyqt

Each row is a QHBoxLayout, I want all of the gray space to be used up by the layout and I want the first widget to use all of the space. How can I make that happen? This is my current setup:

**Layout:**

layoutStretch: 1,0,0,0

layoutSizeConstraint: SetMaximumSize

**The first element has the following:**

sizePolicy: [Expanding, Preferred, 5, 0]

This currently behaves correctly, it's when I maximize the window that the extra space appears.

[image: Screenshot of my layout]

Comment: Did you set a `maximumSize` or `maximumWidth` for the first widget? It looks like they grow up to a certain width.

Comment: I would recommend showing a bit of sample code for the layout and the first widget.

Comment: @Avaris got it 100% correct, but you don't have an answer for me to mark correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the first widget is constrained by the `maximumWidth`. Leave it at the default (`16777215`) so that it can grow as much as needed.